# How many TCP connections can a server handle from a Load Balancer

Tags: performance, tcp, architecture, load-balancing, scalability

As I understand, the max number of TCP connections to a server from a single client IP Address is ~64k connections.

However, what I am not clear about is max number of connections that a server can handle, behind a single load balancer considering that the connections terminate on the Load balancer. Is it ~64k only because there is only one IP from which the server can receive requests?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, upstream server can handle only 64k connections from the same client due to limitation of ephemeral port range at client side.

But you can assign several IP addresses to the same private interface of your load balancer and force server to use them in a round-robin fashion.

You can define several networks on the same interface of load balancer, for example:

- 192.168.1.1,
- 192.168.2.1,
- 192.168.3.1

And define corresponding extra IP addresses at upstream server:

- 192.168.1.2,
- 192.168.2.2,
- 192.168.3.2 .

With following upstream configuration load balancer will pass requests to the same upstream server while using different IP addresses:

```
upstream ipproxy {
  server 192.168.1.2:some-port;
  server 192.168.2.2:some-port;
  server 192.168.3.2:some-port;
}
```

Load balancer will be forced to use different IP addresses thus allowing you to bypass 64k connection limitation and achieve 192k connections.